# Embed an activity in a tabbed UI from external applications

Tags: android

I want to make an application which embeds an activity in a tabbed UI from a number of applications. As far as I know it's *officially* disabled due to the security matter but probably some hacks exist!

I have heard of two ways:

1. converting the activity to a type of `Fragment`
2. using `LocalActivityManager` class which is currently deprecated.

I already tried both of them and failed due to lack of my ability. If there is something I missed or another approach, let me know!

Note that I can modify those because I have a source code of them.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make an application which embeds an activity in a tabbed UI from a number of applications.

That is not possible.

> As far as I know it's officially disabled due to the security matter but probably some hacks exist!

I doubt it.

> I have heard of two ways

Neither of them are related to your problem as originally stated.

> Note that I can modify those because I have a source code of them.

Then combine them into one application, creating one APK file. At that point, *then* you can start exploring converting UIs into fragments or otherwise combining things into a tabbed UI.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but i dont want to combine them into one!

Comment: @RexKim: Then you will have to get rid of your tabbed UI. Or, write your own fork of Android that offers what you want, roll that fork into a custom ROM, and convince people to install that ROM on their devices.